# None of the asp.net login controls work in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

This is really strange, but I originally had a Visual Studio 2008 web forms application that I upgraded to .Net 4 but the IDE is Visual Studio 2012.

My membership system worked great before the upgrade, now it is completely broken.

I actually recreated the login controls, login, password recovery, register in an Account folder.  I changed the reference to my login path in web.config.

I also checked the Asp.net configuration page to see if it sees my users and YES it does.
However when I attempt to login, it reports back a failure.  I verified the username was correct and just in case somehow the password changed, I tried using the password recovery form.

The password recovery form reports back that it can't find the user name.  I have triple checked that the user name (an email address) is correct, in both the configuration and the database.  It's there and spelled right.

What is going on???

Thanks

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FolderPath" value="xCellFiles/" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="SalonConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=76.71.167.122;Initial Catalog=databasename;User Id=id;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" />
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
      <eventMappings>
        <clear />
        <!-- Log ALL error events -->
        <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
        <!-- Log application startup/shutdown events -->
        <add name="Application Events" type="System.Web.Management.WebApplicationLifetimeEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
      </eventMappings>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <!-- Provide any customized SqlWebEventProvider information here (such as a different connection string name value -->
        <add connectionStringName="SalonConnectionString" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="false" name="SqlWebEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" />
      </providers>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
        <add name="Application Events Default" eventName="Application Events" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
    <!-- reduces size of http response (removes x-aspnet-version) -->
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <trust level="Full" />
    <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this
            affects performance, set this value to true only
            during development.

            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions
            where data loss can occur.
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear />
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
        <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
        <add namespace="System.Text" />
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
        <add namespace="System.Web" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />-->
    <!-- Gets and sets the amount of time, in minutes, allowed between requests before the session-state provider terminates the session.
    Default is 20 minute.
    -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="900" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="900" defaultUrl="/Stylist/Redirecting.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="SiteMap provider which reads in .sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration
            of the security authentication mode used by
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user.
        -->
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs
            during the execution of a request. Specifically,
            it enables developers to configure html error pages
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
            <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="LoginReg.aspx" />
</customErrors>
   -->
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/GeneralErrorPage.aspx" mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="15" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="SalonSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SalonSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="SalonConnectionString"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/Service2020"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d).*$" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SalonNetRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SalonNetRoleProvider" connectionStringName="SalonConnectionString" applicationName="/Service2020" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider,                           &#xA;             System.Web,&#xA;                                             Version=2.0.0.0,&#xA;                                             &#xA;                                       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <location path="ChangePassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="PasswordRecovery.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mail@address.com">
        <network host="mail.address.com" password="password" userName="mail@address.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <!--<system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
         <webServices>
            <authenticationService enabled="true" />
         </webServices>
      </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>-->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <!--<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="UnauthorizedAccess.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <!--<staticContent> when getting ready to beta include in release
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>-->
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.7.123" newVersion="3.5.7.123" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, they are all broken. Microsoft call this 'by design'.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Any way around this.  Piece by piece the whole program is being ported over to MVC, but for now I need to have this working.  Any ideas??

Comment: Have you stepped through the code under the debugger?  Are these accounts in a database?  Have you logged the SQL statements to see exactly what's going on?  I doubt anyone here can just *guess* what the problem is without seeing all the code.

Comment: My login tools used to be more customized, but they wouldn't work anymore, so I just went directly to using the controls. There is no code behind or anything to walk through.  It's purely the controls

Comment: Must be a configuration related issue (web.config?), so you should post that information..

Comment: @Sheri What version of MVC are you updating up to?

Comment: This is still a web forms application.  It will run side by side with MVC until everything is converted.  I am just checking errors from the upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 .Net 4 Web Forms.  More errors when I tried going to 4.5, so I dropped back to 4. Application was originally built using VS 2008 .Net 3.5.

Comment: @Sheri You forgot to remove your mail settings password before posting your config file, be sure to change it asap!

Comment: @Sheri do any errors appear on the screen? either when you re-compile the application or when you run it?

Comment: No, none. It doesn't appear that the controls even look at the user table to see if the user exists. It used to have no problem when using 3.5, but now nothing will work.

Comment: Also what OS and service pack do you have installed?

Comment: I am working on Windows 7 Pro and whatever the latest service packs are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following Microsoft links

**hashing algorithms**

```
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770148
```

**root configurations**

```
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770149
```

**main document link**

```
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes
```

It really matters on which SP you have installed as it may decide the outcome on which route you take to resolve your issue. Also you will need to know if the  **KB958854** hotfix is installed or not, you can find this by looking in your Add/Remove programs list (view installed updates - top left of that window)

Also maybe as simple test (first) you could add the following element into your config file under the SYSTEM.WEB section

```
<machineKey validation="SHA1" />
```

which will revert the hashing algorithm back to the older format HMACSHA1 and not the newer algorithm which is HMACSHA256 If that fixes it Fine, if not simply remove the element again.

Comment: Also this ought to be interest to you http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/7/B57D25A2-B3FD-4668-91B9-DB43B6BD910D/NETFx4RTM.htm#General Issues (sections: 2.3.2.1 and 2.3.2.11 and 2.3.2.12 especially **2.3.2.16**)

Comment: Zaf Khan... Thank you so much.  The machine key worked.  I will read all the info you provided.
Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sheri, Your welcome, also, you can find further information about the System.Security.Cryptography Namespace here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx